# MaxBackupIndex is not working with log4j 1.2.17

Tags: java, log4j

I am using `DailyRollingFileAppender` in Log4J 1.2.17 and want to keep back up for last 10 days.

```
# Keep last 10 files
#log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

But When I run it it shows error. Is there any other alternate of MaxBackupIndex?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: error: MaxBackupIndex is not supported in log4j 1.2.17